# Qt widgets for HDR image display

Tags: image, qt, qt4, widget, hdr

I'm currently developing a consrol software for a camera that delivers 14 bit/sample grayscale images (specifically it's a scientific x-ray camera).

So far I just used the upper 8 bits and passed those to a QImage, so that I could see something. However now I need to show all detail, a widget that supports HDR and tone/pseudocolour mapping is needed.

Before I start developing such a widget and subclass QImage for HDR support I'd like to know if someone already did this for Qt and published the source under LGPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VTK](http://www.vtk.org) has really good Qt widgets and supports everything what you may need for medical imaging.

Currently we use [ParaView](http://www.paraview.org). ParaView is based on VTK and Qt, fully open source and easily extensible.

Comment: Well, it's not medical imaging, but crystallography. Otherwise it may be the right tool, so thanks!